# Is there any Magento Best tutorial for backend development from scratch?

Tags: magento-1.9, backend, development

I want to know about the backend code development. Is there any good tutorial or videos available to learn? Suggest me about the development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To develop any module or customize the code you need to understand the structure of magento.

1. It explains about the step by step guide for module development and structure of magento

https://www.multidots.com/step-by-step-guide-for-magento-module-development

2. It explains about custom module development

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/magento-custom-module-development--cms-20643

3. This is one of the best one for the beginers

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/magento/

Answer (score 0):

https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/magento-2-demo.html .Here is an overview of magento 2 backend.At the same time you can go through Nexcess,aster web..etc training in youtube.

Comment: I need for magento -1 @ren

Comment: sorry i dony know much about..why cant you use magento2.At first time i also used magento 1,but later i understood the features of magento 2 and started working on it.In you tube there is a 2 hour video about the magento 1 and almost it covers all the area.(Audio is not that much clear)

Comment: Can you share me the link or name of the 2 hours video?

Comment: sorry for the delay .please go through this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zmKAzEvlras

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend this 12 hours course on Udemy. It teaches the core concept with real live project. https://www.udemy.com/simplified-magento-2-video-course-from-beginner-to-expert/ Disclaimer: I was part of the creator of the course.

After that, you can go for Magento study group. I found it quite useful https://u.magento.com/magento-2-certified-professional-developer